# Python - Reading a data text file with different delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a file in which fields are separated by a ':', subfields are separated by a ';', and items within subfields are separated by a ','.

I would like to read it Python. After a bit of time, I could probably read it line by line, and then splitting everything, but I believe something already exist for that kind of thing ?

A line of the file :

```
   0 :   16,  250 :  1 :  0.053 :RIG : DIS :  1 :   48, 220;  2 :   42, 241;  2 :   43, 251;  3 :   25, 266;  1 :   36, 287;  2
```

I actually tried :

```
Dat = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter= ':', dtype = None, skip_header = 4,  skip_footer = 5, encoding = None)
```

For a reason I do not understand, it only gives me back the first column of the file. However, it works if i change to `delimiter= ','`.

That gives me 7 fields, that I can actually split myself.

Then:
1) How would you do to read that file ?
2) Using np.genfromtxt, why do I obtain only the first column using ':' as delimiter ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution using pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt',
                   sep=";|:|,",
                   header=None,
                   engine='python')
```

This will write every value in a new column. Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: I just had to correct the header lines, but it works perfectly. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
In [280]: txt=['   0 :   16,  250 :  1 :  0.053 :RIG : DIS :  1 :   48, 220;  2 
     ...: :   42, 241;  2 :   43, 251;  3 :   25, 266;  1 :   36, 287;  2 '
     ...: ]

In [282]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=':',dtype=None, encoding=None)
Out[282]: 
array((0, '   16,  250 ', 1, 0.053, 'RIG ', ' DIS ', 1, '   48, 220;  2 ', '   42, 241;  2 ', '   43, 251;  3 ', '   25, 266;  1 ', '   36, 287;  2'),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U12'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<U4'), ('f5', '<U5'), ('f6', '<i8'), ('f7', '<U15'), ('f8', '<U15'), ('f9', '<U15'), ('f10', '<U15'), ('f11', '<U14')])
```

This is structured array with 11 fields, a mix of integer, string and floats.  That's because `dtype=None` tells it to deduce the dtype for each column.

Splitting on `,` produces a 7 column array (here 1d because there's only one input line, but it would be 2d with more):

```
In [283]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter=',',dtype=None, encoding=None)
Out[283]: 
array(['0 :   16', '  250 :  1 :  0.053 :RIG : DIS :  1 :   48',
       ' 220;  2 :   42', ' 241;  2 :   43', ' 251;  3 :   25',
       ' 266;  1 :   36', ' 287;  2'], dtype='<U42')
```

But note, is all strings.

`genfromtxt` doesn't take multiple delimiters, but it does accept input from anything that feeds it lines.

So if I define a function that replaces the delimiters:

```
In [285]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     return astr.replace(':',',').replace(';',',')
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [286]: np.genfromtxt([foo(a) for a in txt],delimiter=',',dtype=None, encoding
     ...: =None)
Out[286]: 
array((0, 16, 250, 1, 0.053, 'RIG ', ' DIS ', 1, 48, 220, 2, 42, 241, 2, 43, 251, 3, 25, 266, 1, 36, 287, 2),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<U4'), ('f6', '<U5'), ('f7', '<i8'), ('f8', '<i8'), ('f9', '<i8'), ('f10', '<i8'), ('f11', '<i8'), ('f12', '<i8'), ('f13', '<i8'), ('f14', '<i8'), ('f15', '<i8'), ('f16', '<i8'), ('f17', '<i8'), ('f18', '<i8'), ('f19', '<i8'), ('f20', '<i8'), ('f21', '<i8'), ('f22', '<i8')])
```

Now I've broken the input into a structured array with 23 fields, again a mix of ints, floats and (smaller) strings.

`genfromtxt` lets me define a `dtype`, one which could group the subfields together.

For example just trying to handle the first 6 columns:

```
In [298]: dt = np.dtype([('f0','i'),('f1','i',2),('f2','i'),('f3','i'),('f4','U3
     ...: ')])
In [299]: np.genfromtxt([foo(a) for a in txt],delimiter=',',dtype=dt, encoding=N
     ...: one,usecols=range(6))
Out[299]: 
array((0, [ 16, 250], 1, 0, 'RIG'),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4', (2,)), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<U3')])
```

I've grouped the `'16,250'` into one field that contains 2 ints. Later ' 48,220; 2,42,241;2' could nest 3 fields (defined by ';'), and within those 2,2 and 1 subfields.

`genfromtxt` accepts another form of delimiter - fixed field widths.

---

Speedwise, `genfromtxt` does not offer any improvement over rolling your own.  It still has to read each line, split it, and collect the values to a list of lists.  At the end it converts that into an array.

`pandas` has a faster `csv` reader, but this case may be too complex to use that.  The `engine=python` parameter forces it to use a slower all python version.